# Некорректная работа команды при запуске планировщика CRON для пользователя

Tags: bash, cron

Возникла проблема при создании задачи для планировщика cron для обычного пользователя. А именно, некорректная работа команды для пользователя ufo. Вот лог, работы crontab для пользователя ufo.

```
авг 23 13:58:01 e-praktika2 CROND[4205]: (ufo) CMD (echo ~ )
авг 23 13:58:01 e-praktika2 CROND[4198]: (ufo) CMDOUT (/)
```

Вопрос: почему при запуске команды планировщика `echo ~` выводится `/` а не `/home/ufo`? Ведь когда я пишу команду в консоли ufo: `echo ~` мне выводится в консоль: `/home/ufo` Тогда от какого пользователя запускается команда в планировщике `echo ~`?

Comment: неплохо бы увидеть само задание для cron, возможно в нем есть `HOME=/`

Comment: Дейстивтельно) Не обратил на это внимание. Спасибо. 
Подскажите ещё, можно ли отправлять лог работы cron в историю логирования пользователя, а не root'a? Просто сейчас весь лог просматривается через root'a, но почему-то у самого пользователя нет никакой информации о работе cron... Другими словами, я бы хотел, чтобы пользователь мог просматривать лог также как и root: 
`авг 23 13:58:01 e-praktika2 CROND[4205]: (ufo) CMD (echo ~ )
авг 23 13:58:01 e-praktika2 CROND[4198]: (ufo) CMDOUT (/)`

Comment: Создать для пользователя отдельный файл с заданиями и указать `MAILTO=ufo` вместо `MAILTO=root`, возможно вы об этом параметре говорите.

Comment: `SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=ufo
HOME=/`
Вот так выглядят переменные окружения сейчас. я прописал MAILTO=ufo, но это не принесло нужного эффекта...

Comment: а reload/restart службы крон делали? Потом под пользователем команду mail, что бы посмотреть сообщения для него.

Comment: Не знаю почему, но у меня нет файла /etc/init.d/cron... Есть какой-то другой способ перезагрузить крон?

Comment: все зависит от версии ОС, обычно это /etc/init.d/crond restart, либо systemctl restart crond, либо service crond restart

Comment: задачи крона не нуждаются в перезапуске демона. смотрите логи в почте через `mail` - если MTA настроен на локальную доставку

Answer (score 0):

Из мануала `man 5 crontab`:

> Several environment variables are set up automatically by the cron(8) daemon. SHELL is set to /bin/sh, and LOGNAME and **HOME are set from the /etc/passwd line of the crontab's  owner**.  PATH  is  set  to "/usr/bin:/bin".  HOME, SHELL, and PATH may be overridden by settings in the crontab; LOGNAME is the user that the job is running from, and may not be changed.

То есть, переменная `HOME` установлена не по умолчанию.
Проверте переменные окружения с  `crontab -l` и установите их с `crontab -e`.